Using shinylive to add a shiny app to the readme or an article of a pkgdown website on GitHub pages
I have some R packages on GitHub, mostly they contain small-ish datasets with a few helper functions for data preparation and plotting. I've started using GitHub pages to make the data and documentation and plots more accessible for non-coders. I'd like to add some interactivity to allow the non-coders to subset and explore the data. I have found several examples using shinylive on GitHub pages, and I've found tutorials on how to include a shiny app in an R package, but I haven't found any examples using Shinylive in an R package on Github Pages.
I'd like to put the app in one of the package "Articles" (an article is just a vignette that goes in the pkgdown website but not in the R package documentation). Seems like this should be easy, but I'm struggling.
Here's the GitHub page I'm working on: https://capellett.github.io/scpopulation/index.html
I've built the app ui and server functions in the R/ folder, and I have an app.R file in the root folder, and a GitHub action:
usethis::use_github_action( url="https://github.com/posit-dev/r-shinylive/blob/actions-v1/examples/deploy-app.yaml") 


Some relevant info here: https://github.com/posit-dev/r-shinylive/issues/142  which suggests roxy.shinylive package: https://insightsengineering.github.io/roxy.shinylive/main/
